# How to read only bolded cells in a worksheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using openpyxl to iterate through a column in my excel document to search for cells that have bolded text. If the cell is bolded text, return the value of the cell.

What if statement can I use that will return True or False if the cell is bolded?

I have tried:

```
if ws["cell"].font == Font(bold=True):
```

but this does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if ws["cell"].font.bold:
   ###
```